# Адаптивная иконка под локализацию приложения

Tags: java, android

Можно ли как то  сделать чтобы иконка менялась в зависимости от локализации приложения.(На русском языке одна ,на английском другая !)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Да, можно. Для любых ресурсов можно

Правой кнопочкой по папке res в структуре проекта -> New -> Android Resource Directory

Выбираете drawable(или любую другую). Слева список "параметров" папки. Выбираете Locale, справа указываете, например, en. Теперь когда у юзера телефон использует англоязычную локаль, возьмутся ресурсы с папки drawable-en, если их там нет - из основной папки drawable