# Как локализовать этот файл

Tags: java, android, android-resources

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как  локализовать папку Res  (в ней у меня нужный файл)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

вы не можете положить что-либо просто в папку res, тем более манифест. Даже не представляю как вы получили ситуацию на скрине. Перенесите иконку в папку drawable.

Про локализацию папок только что ответил в [другом вопросе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1038492/%D0%90%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F-%D0%B8%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BD%D0%BA%D0%B0-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F). Целиком папку res локализовать нельзя, каждую ресурсную папку нужно локализовать отдельно

Comment: когда я создаю иконку она сама на то место  прописывается сейчас добавлю скрин в описание